# Count the number of observations between two curving boundaries

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a dataset with N observations and two non-overlapping boundaries (one higher and another lower). I want to analyse my observations relative to these boundaries: to see how many of the observations are (1) higher than both boundaries, (2) between two boundaries, and (3) below both boundaries.

Here is a simplified version of my data.

```
data_line1 <- data.frame(line = "1", x = c(0, round(runif(18,0,10), 2), 10), y = round(runif(20,40,60), 2))
data_line2 <- data.frame(line = "2", x = c(0, round(runif(18,0,10), 2), 10), y = round(runif(20,0,39), 2))
data_dots <- data.frame(x = round(runif(200,0,10), 2), y = round(runif(100,0,60), 2))

plot <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = data_line1, aes(x,y), color = "black")+
  geom_line(data = data_line2, aes(x,y), color = "red")+
  geom_point(data = data_dots, aes(x,y), color = "deepskyblue")
```

[image]

I am pretty sure there should be an elegant solution to this problem, however I was not able to come up with anything on paper before even starting to try in R (which I am also relatively new to).

Comment: For each dot, do you know the value of the upper line and lower line?  If not, am I correct in assuming that you want a linear extrapolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each point in `data_dots`, you need to find out whether the y value is higher than each line at the equivalent x value. To do this, you need to interpolate the points making up each line. We can do this with `approxfun`:

```r
data_dots$line1_value <- approxfun(data_line1$x, data_line1$y)(data_dots$x)
data_dots$line2_value <- approxfun(data_line2$x, data_line2$y)(data_dots$x)
data_dots$group <- with(data_dots, 1 + (y > line2_value) + (y > line1_value))
```

Now we can give each group an appropriate label depending on whether it is above or below each line:

```r
data_dots$group <- c('below', 'between', 'above')[data_dots$group]
```

To show this works, let us plot the points according to their group:

```r
ggplot(data = data_line1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(data = data_dots, aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = data_line2)
```

[image]

To get the actual numbers in each group, we can simply use `table`:

```r
table(data_dots$group)
#> above   below between 
#>    35      59     106
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `approxfun` to define interpolation functions for both lower and upper bounds, and then check if `y` is in between two bounds with given `x` for data from `data_dots`, e.g.,

```
fu <- with(data_line1, approxfun(x, y))
fl <- with(data_line2, approxfun(x, y))
with(data_dots, sum(y >= fl(x) & y <= fu(x)))
```

which counts the number of points within bounds.

---

For the visualization, you can try

```
fu <- with(data_line1, approxfun(x, y))
fl <- with(data_line2, approxfun(x, y))
idx <- with(data_dots, y >= fl(x) & y <= fu(x))

plot +
    geom_point(data = data_dots[idx, ], aes(x, y), color = "purple", size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was writing up the same answer when you posted! I will keep mine because it adds a bit of visual intuition.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, please keep yours. I am not proficient as you in data visualization so I also need to learn :)